# When enumerating Projects in DevOps, is there a way to determine if a Pipeline exists on the project?

Tags: azure-devops

So far I have used this code to grab our azure devops project data. I have poked around the data and any urls returned looking for data related to pipelines and found nothing

```
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalAccessToken)));

ListofProjectsResponse.Projects viewModel = null;

//use the httpclient
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://acme.visualstudio.com");  //url of our account
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?stateFilter=All&api-version=1.0").Result;

    //check to see if we have a succesfull respond
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //set the viewmodel from the content in the response
        viewModel = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ListofProjectsResponse.Projects>().Result;


 }
}
    public class ListofProjectsResponse
    {
        public class Projects
        {
            public int count { get; set; }
            public Value[] value { get; set; }
        }

        public class Value
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This seems to be an old version of API. Are you sure that your tragte is Azure DevOps. Can you add doc refernce which you used to write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found is to enumerate the builds for each project using the same code as above except

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/{org name}/{project 
name}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1").Result;
```

The url for each build will  return a json collection with any azure build pipline data inside of "queue"

Answer (score 1):

Did some changes on your main work code and share it below, just have a try:

```
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", "{PAT}")));

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://acme.visualstudio.com");  //url of our account
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);

                //HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/_apis/projects?stateFilter=All&api-version=1.0").Result;
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/ForMerlin/_apis/projects"))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
               // Console.WriteLine(response);

            }
```

[image]

---

For `BaseAddress`, what you were using is an old URL format which like `https://{org name}.visualstudio.com`. This URL format has contain the organization name in it, so you can ignore the `organization name` when calling `GetAsync`. Just make it be `/_apis/projects?stateFilter=All&api-version=1.0` is okay.

Comment: Thanks for the code update but did not solve the issue

Comment: @Theo Really？With above code, I can get all project data of my organization, see the screenshot.

Comment: Unless I overlooked something I saw nothing indicative of a build pipeline in the project when I grabbed the JSON for it. I found it when I pulled the builds list for the project as described below.